# Proving there is a degree 1 unit in $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ if $p^2|n$ for some prime $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I think this can be done by contradiction.  Suppose not.  Then $\forall f \in \mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ of degree $1$ there does not exist $g \in \mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ such that $fg=1$, but I don't know where to go from here.

This might not be the best approach though.  I don't understand what $U(R[x])) = U(R)$ means because isn't $U(R)$ all polynomials of degree $0$?  Can someone please explain this and give me a hint?

Comment: $U(R)$ is all *invertible* polynomials of degree $0$. For example, if $R=\Bbb Z$ then $U(R) = \{1,-1\}$; if $R = \Bbb Z_n$ then $U(R)$ has $\phi(n)$ elements. Hint: if $n\mid k^2$ but $n\nmid k$, then $1-kx$ and $1+kx$ are inverses of each other and thus both degree-1 units. Can you use the assumption $p^2\mid n$ to choose a suitable $k$?

Comment: @GregMartin of course they're invertible.  I just meant that every element of $U(R)$ has degree $0$.  I'm not sure about the condition necessary for k? $(1-kx)(1+kx) = 1+k^2x$ so we want $k^2x = 0 mod n$ so $k^2 = 0 mod n$?

Comment: Indeed, as @GregMartin says, you don’t want to do it by contradiction but rather by exhibiting such a unit.

Comment: @Lubin How do I go about doing that?  I don't see the conditions that need to be imposed on $k$ as Greg mentioned?

Comment: Well, I hate to hand it to you on a platter. Notice that if $n=p^2m$, then $(pm)^2\equiv0\pmod n$ .